# GatsbyJS and Contentful: data coming up undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, contentful, gatsby

I have a Header component in my layout folder, and have made a query to pull out some data. However, when I console.log out this.props.data, I get a result of 'undefined'. Where am I going wrong here? Have I forgotten something in my query?

code for Header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {

        console.log(this.props.data)

      return (
         code for component
      );
    }
  }

  export const headerQuery = graphql`
    query headerQuery {
        allContentfulBlogPost {
            edges {
                node {
                    postTitle
                    postDate
                }
            }
            totalCount
        }
    }
`
```

Comment: Does the query return response in your local `graphql` server?

Comment: yes, it works. i have the exact same query in another component as well, and that is working fine.

Comment: AFAIK it's still not possible to run queries inside components. Move it to a page and call it `pageQuery` or `query`. Almost certainly `headerQuery` is just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can only fetch data from Gatsby via the `pageQuery` export on a page component. It is not possible to fetch data in other components. This is necessary to allow Gatsby to statically compile your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your components into /pages folder, restart server again, or through `createPage` api in `gatsby-node.js`